# Is there an argsort function in java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'd like to use an `argsort` function on arrays or arraylist or an other data structure in Java but I didn't find in the documentation an `argsort` function. I know there is a `sort` method on the `Collections` class but there isn't any `argsort` method. Is there any class with an `argsort` method already implemented?

Comment: I know what argsort do, it returns the indices that would sort the array. I am only looking for a class with this method already implemented

Comment: maybe this source can help you : https://code.google.com/p/array4j/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/net/lunglet/util/ArrayUtils.java?r=306

Comment: I am able to write this method in java too, that's not very difficult, but I was looking for a class that implements it, like the sort method...

Answer (score 8):

I've found this class, I hope it's what you wanted:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Random;

public final class ArrayUtils {
    public static int[] argsort(final float[] a) {
        return argsort(a, true);
    }

    public static int[] argsort(final float[] a, final boolean ascending) {
        Integer[] indexes = new Integer[a.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
            indexes[i] = i;
        }
        Arrays.sort(indexes, new Comparator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(final Integer i1, final Integer i2) {
                return (ascending ? 1 : -1) * Float.compare(a[i1], a[i2]);
            }
        });
        return asArray(indexes);
    }

    public static <T extends Number> int[] asArray(final T... a) {
        int[] b = new int[a.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            b[i] = a[i].intValue();
        }
        return b;
    }

    public static double[] castOf(final float[] x) {
        double[] y = new double[x.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            y[i] = x[i];
        }
        return y;
    }

    public static int[] castOf(final long[] original) {
        return castOf(original, original.length);
    }

    public static int[] castOf(final long[] original, final int newLength) {
        int[] cast = new int[newLength];
        int length = Math.min(cast.length, original.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            long o = original[i];
            if (o < Integer.MIN_VALUE || o > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            cast[i] = (int) o;
        }
        return cast;
    }

    public static float[][] copyOf(final float[][] x, final int newLength) {
        float[][] y = new float[newLength][];
        for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            if (x[i] != null) {
                y[i] = Arrays.copyOf(x[i], x[i].length);
            }
        }
        return y;
    }

    /**
     * Assigns a random value to each element of the specified array of doubles.
     */
    public static void fillRandom(final double[] x, final Random rng) {
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i] = rng.nextDouble();
        }
    }

    private ArrayUtils() {
    }
}
```

**Link:** [Code](https://code.google.com/p/array4j/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/net/lunglet/util/ArrayUtils.java?r=306)

Comment: I found it already (I did a bit of research on the web too before asking my question), but I was wondering why there wasn't any class with this argsort method. It exists in Python numpy for instance...

Comment: @fonfonx Yeah I know but not in Java as it seems :D Just use this one instead. Oh and is this question now answered? Or should we still search for it? :D

Comment: could you add only the relevant part of the code and explain a little bit. Pasting code you did not write is not an answer.

Comment: @Hacketo I never said I wrote this code and I did not understand what he really wants so I pasted him this and added a Link to the original site

Comment: If you don't understand what OP want, how did you find this piece of code ? I never said you wrote this, you pasted code you did not write without explanation and without highlighting the relevant part

Comment: Relax, I just wanted to know if there was a class I can import with the argsort method in it, in the same manner as I write `import java.util.Arrays;` and `Arrays.sort(...)` but it seems that there is no `Arrays.argsort(...)`. But never mind I wrote some piece of code to implement it, but it would have been easier not to write it again...

Answer (score 2):

As of 2017, you can find an [argsort function in the ND4J library](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/nd4j/blob/3c276c8a245b491c6b2116ab9db08eae017d0348/nd4j-common/src/main/java/org/nd4j/linalg/util/ArrayUtil.java#L883) (which is probably the closest Java equivalent to numpy). It didn't make it into the 0.9.1 release in 2017, but it looks as though it will be in the upcoming 0.9.2 release. The code is actually derived from the array4j code that JetStream copied into their answer. array4j seems to be abandoned now, so ND4J will probably be preferable as soon as argsort has made it into a release. Once 0.9.2 is released, you'll be able to install it from the [Maven Central repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22nd4j%22).

Incidentally, you mention in a comment on JetStream's answer that

> I was wondering why there wasn't any class with this argsort method. It exists in Python numpy for instance...

That's not a fair comparison, since numpy isn't part of the Python standard libraries, any more than ND4J is for Java. Neither language includes argsort in the standard libraries, and both have it available in a third-party library.